# Creating and populating a drop down menu in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I know I am probably the 500th person to ask, but I have tried everything suggested here and elsewhere to get a dropdown menu, and it won't work, at least not without ruining everything else.

So, I have a table routes, and a table places.

```
 ______________
|Routes        |  
|______________|  
|routeID       |  
|label         |  
|dayprice1     |        __________
|dayprice2     |       |Places    |
|nightprice1   |       |__________|
|nightprice2   |    ---|placeID   |
|distance      |  / |  |place     |
|start         |-/  |  |__________|
|end           |---/
|______________|
```

The part I am currently working on is the routes and places MVCs. What I hope to achieve is a dropdown menu for the fields routes.start and routes.end. They have the placeID as a foreign key. I also set $primaryKey myself.

My problem is this:

if I use $hasMany as a variable in the Model, and use `$this->set('places', $this->Route->Place->find('list'))` in the Controller, and `$this->Form->input('place_id')` in my View, my other functions like edit(), viewAll() and so on will not work any more. I get a LEFT JOIN or similar on my tables, but with place_id instead of placeID. More importantly, my drop down fields are not populated at first, only after I click the `Save` button.

I also tried variations in the input field, using a variable to store my array and calling it in view like this.`$this->Form->input(start, array(option => $array))`. It won't work either. Help?

Edit:

Allright, here is the code for the my model. It's just a standard add function. Controller:

```
public function add() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Route->create();
        if($this->Route->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Daten wurden hinzugefügt.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
       $this->Session->setFlash(__('Daten konnten nicht gespeichert werden!'));

    }

}
```

Model:

```
<!-- File: /app/View/Posts/add.ctp -->  

<h1>Route hinzufügen</h1>  
<?php  

echo $this->Form->create('Route', array('label'=> 'Route'));  
echo $this->Form->input('routeID', array('hidden', 'label'=> 'Routen- ID'));  
echo $this->Form->input('label', array('label'=> 'Name'));  
echo $this->Form->input('dayprice1', array('label'=> 'Tagpreis 1'));  
echo $this->Form->input('dayprice2', array('label'=> 'Tagpreis 2'));  
echo $this->Form->input('nightprice1', array('label'=> 'Nachtpreis 1'));  
echo $this->Form->input('nightprice2', array('label'=> 'Nachtpreis 2'));   
echo $this->Form->input('distance', array('label'=> 'Distanz'));  
echo $this->Form->input('start', array('label'=>'Start'));  
echo $this->Form->input('end', array('label'=> 'Ende'));  
echo $this->Form->end('Speichern');  
?>
```

Comment: How did you define your Model association? Furthermore you don't follow conventions by using `routeID`. Have you made sure that you have added the `primaryKey` attribute in your models?

Comment: set public $displayField = 'place'; in your Place model

Comment: make sure you load your model. $this->loadModel('Route'); - if you still see there is a problem you have problem with your model. then stright try this to see if you are retrieving data.

Comment: There's no code in the question (you need to add your relevant controller action and view). What does (in specific terms such as the obtained error message)  "will not work any more" and "won't work either" mean? Also please tag the question with the versio nof CakePHP that you are using.

Comment: I cannot follow conventions because it is not my Database model, I just have to work with what I've been given... Sorry.

Comment: I don't know what  more I can say about the problem- if I use the suggested method, the fields don't have the correct name, i. e. are not stored as they have to be in the DB. I get the error I added in the Controller: "'Daten konnten nicht gespeichert werden!'" which translates to "Data could not be saved.". So no DB error message itself.

Comment: As to the other methods I have, for example: viewAll() which just gets all data from the DB with a foreach loop- there appears to be a left join on routes with my places table. Which wouldn't be a problem if it weren't for the changed foreign key "place_id" instead of "placeID". I tried defining $foreignKey, but I believe it is not supported. So, I'm kinda stuck.

The other problem is with my dropdown fields, they are not populated at first, only after I click save, and get an error to fill out my fields, they show the set $displayName.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help, I did it! I had `$foobar = $this->set('places', $this->Route->Place->find('list'))` at the wrong place, inside the first `if{}` of my function! With the right model associations it worked just fine!

First of all I had to add a variable
    `var $belongsTo = array('Place' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'placeID'
        ));`
to Model Route, and a
`var $hasMany = 'Route'`
to Model Places.
Then I had to place the line `$foobar = $this->set('places', $this->Route->Place->find('list'))` directly at the beginning of the function- stupid me, of course the variable gets unset as soon as I call the page. So that did it! I can now call my list with `echo $this->Form->input('start', array('label'=>'Start', 'options'=> $foobar));`